# How could I create a webapi of the .NET 5 version using the dotnet cli?

Tags: c#, .net, version, .net-5, dotnet-cli

How could I create a webapi of the .NET 5 version using the dotnet cli?

Whenever I run the `dotnet new webapi` I am getting the .NET Core 3.1 project. I have the .NET 5 installed locally. How could I make the .NET 5 a default version for the dotnet cli?

I tried running the

> $ dotnet new webapi --framework "net5.0"

but it gives me an error:

> Couldn't find an installed template that matches the input, searching online for one that does...

Here is the result of running the `dotnet --info`:

```
$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.301
 Commit:    7feb845744

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19041
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.301\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.7
  Commit:  556582d964

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: what do you get for  `dotnet --version`?

Comment: install and use .NET SDK 5.0 https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

Comment: @FireAlkazar, that helped thanks. I was confused, because I thought that having only runtime would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dotnet new webapi -o projectName --framework "net5.0"

NB: Change projectName to the name of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Just type "dotnet new webapi -f net5.0" . That should do the trick

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Here, **-f** is the acronym of `framework`